# How to hide Ckeditor on onblur

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm displaying an array in HTML page. On a text column when onfocus event is fired i display the text in CKedit using CKEDITOR.replace('#elementId').
I would like hide the CKeditor once the element is not anymore selected (using onblur event) and display unformated text as it was before selecting the element.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think, only way is destroy instance of CKEditor

```
CKEDITOR.instances["YourInstanceID"].destroy();
```

You can recreate instance again, when needed

```
CKEDITOR.replace("YourInstanceID")
```

But, may be you should check inline version:

[CKEditor inline example](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/inline.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think most convenient will be using [inline editors](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full-all/samples/old/inlineall.html). Which only appear when user select specific element. 
Another option is replacing editor after event and destroy it in other way. But this approach might be a little bit laggy, because editor should be properly destroyed and recreated, what might be time consuming for a browse. [Here](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.8.0/full-all/samples/old/divreplace.html) is an example on doubleclicking the divs, similar approach you could be able to use for focusing and bluring.

Answer (score 0):

Thans for your answers.
I finaly simply added or removed ckeditor editor class in the textarea tag.